# Getting URL values in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a view function that look like this:

```
def search_manager(request, account_id):
    account = Account.objects.get(pk=account_id)
    ...
```

I want to create either middleware or a context processor where I can set some values that will be set for every view. Is there a way I can get `account_id` in middleware or a context processor so I can grab the values I need for all views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use session variables, to set values to a user session, that way every request will include the account_id, so you can access that value from a middleware and other views. In a view or a middleware. Have in mind that a request might not have a session, if a user is not logged in, for example.

```
# set a value
if hasattr(request, 'session'):
    request.session['account_id'] = account_id

# read a value
if hasattr(request, 'session'):
    account_id = request.session['account_id']
```

the session object in Django works like a dictionary.

Comment: If you enable the session middleware, every request sent to a view will contain a session object. That doesn't mean that `account_id` will be set. The checks you have shouldn't be needed, but when reading you should use `if 'account_id' in request.session` or `account_id = request.session.get('account_id')` to prevent KeyErrors from being raised.

Comment: Exactly, that's why I posted the part on setting a value on the session, that way he can set the account_id on the session and use it throughout the site. If he wants something automatically set up, then, if session middleware enabled as you say, he could use the `request.user`